# Why does my switch/case default when using enums?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have the following `switch/case` statement in Arduino 1.8.7 where the variable `led` is an integer:

```
switch (led) {

  case ALL: {
    /* do stuff */
    break;
  }

  case LED1: {
    /* do stuff */
    break;
  }

  case LED2: {
    /* do stuff */
    break;
  }

  case LED3: {
    /* do stuff */
    break;
  }

  case LED4: {
    /* do stuff */
    break;
  }

  default: {
    break;
  }

}
```

I also have the following `enum`:

```
enum LED_References_e
{
  ALL  = 0,
  LED1 = 1,
  LED2 = 2,
  LED3 = 3,
  LED4 = 4
};
```

When using the enumerated values as cases to the statement, the statement *always* hits the `default` clause. If I substitute the enumerated values for the integers that they represent (i.e.`case 0: ... case 1: ...`) then the statement functions as expected.

I have tried, when using the enumerated values within the statement, to reference the enumerator as the value that the switch is performed on:

```
switch ((LED_References_e)led)
```

But this also defaults every time.

I am using another enumerator within my program and this functions correctly, however it is conditionally tested using `if/else` as opposed to `switch/case`.

My question is twofold:

1. Why does the `switch/case` statement seemingly not work with enumerated values?
2. What fundamental difference am I missing between `if/else` and `switch/case`?

Comment: There are probably other names `ALL`, `LED1` etc. in scope at the switch so that the `LED_References_e` ones are not visible. Can you produce a [MCVE] so we can investigate this further?

Comment: Switch statements with enums work fine.  The problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Use an enum class for LED_References_e if you have C++11.

Comment: @PeterRuderman You were correct, constants with the same name were used in another module that I'm importing. Thanks for prompting me to look elsewhere; would have expected some sort of compiler warning but hey ho!

Comment: @AdamMitchell It's not a compiler warning because name shadowing from different scopes is not generally unintended ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/Q2N7I3)). This here in particular is a good reason for using `enum class` though - you can't have these accidents if the other values are of the wrong type in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Max Langhof is correct and there are other names `ALL`, `LED1`, etc... in scope at the switch so that the `LED_References_e` ones are shadowed, this should help:

I'm not 100% certain about the differences between standard C++ and Arduino C++, but you should be able to do the following:

```
enum LED_References_e
{
  ALL  = 0,
  LED1 = 1,
  LED2 = 2,
  LED3 = 3,
  LED4 = 4
};

switch (led) {

  case LED_References_e::ALL: {
    /* do stuff */
    break;
  }

  case LED_References_e::LED1: {
    /* do stuff */
    break;
  }

  case LED_References_e::LED2: {
    /* do stuff */
    break;
  }

  case LED_References_e::LED3: {
    /* do stuff */
    break;
  }

  case LED_References_e::LED4: {
    /* do stuff */
    break;
  }

  default: {
    break;
  }

}
```

What this does is it tells the compiler you explicitly want `LED1`...`LED4` from the `LED_References_e` enum.
If there are other `LEDx`es in the same scope, this should disambiguate.

Comment: You could improve your answer by editing it with a mention of type safe enums (aka `enum class`).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I see that `enum class` was introduced in C++11. I'm unsure about compiler support, and specifically Arduino's.

Answer (score -2):

```
enum LED_References_e {
  ALL  = 0,
  LED1 = 1,
  LED2 = 2,
  LED3 = 3,
  LED4 = 4
};

Void led(LED_References_e led) {
  switch (led) {

    case ALL:
      /* do stuff */
      break;

    case LED1:
      /* do stuff */
      break;

    case LED2:
      /* do stuff */
      break;

    case LED3:
      /* do stuff */
      break;

    case LED4:
      /* do stuff */
      break;

    default:
      break;

  }
}
```